# What is the source of the prohibition of not preparing on Shabbat for after Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory

Preparing on Shabbat for after Shabbat is not one of the 39 *melachot* (Biblical categories of "work").

I gather that many prohibitions are gleaned from [Yeshayahu (Isaiah) 58:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14257&st=&pgnum=449). However, the only thing I could see in this verse is the concept of how to **honor** Shabbat with one of the ways being the phrase *Asot Cheftzecha*. There does not appear to be a specific direct prohibition implied, here. Was this prohibition placed as a *syag* - a "fence" to prevent some other melacha from happening?

Answer (score 3):

[Shabbos 113a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37953&st=&pgnum=236&hilite=) says that one may not prepare the bedspreads from Shabbos to Motzei Shabbos. 
מציעין את המיטות מלילי שבת לשבת, אבל לא משבת למוצאי שבת

[Mishnas Avraham in the Semag - volume 2 - 71](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14550&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=) quoting the Raavad regarding cleaning dishes from Shabbos for the weekday says it is forbidden as it is exerting oneself for the weekday.

I do not think this is a Seyog to prevent other Melacha from happening. It sounds to me more like a lack of Kavod Shabbos.